# Dynamic GPS spoofer

Tags: android, gps

I am looking for an Android application that can change the GPS coordinates to trick other applications into thinking that the Android phone is moving. If possible, it would go to record a path (e.g. working around a building) and replay it in a loop.

In many GPS spoofers, one can only set a fixed GPS location, e.g. [Fake GPS location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en).

Comment: Many such tools will allow the user to provide a point, and then automatically create random aberrations around that point.  Is that sufficient, or do you need to create an entire path?

Comment: By random aberrations you mean randomly change the GPS coordinates around a given point? If so, I'm indeed looking for something else, a tool allowing me to set a path and a  speed.

Comment: You got it... that's what I meant.  I always questioned the value of introducing random aberrations, as a quick analysis would show what is being done.

Answer (score 3):

[GPS Route Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forgottenprojects.mocklocations&hl=en) seems to fit the bill.

it is used to simulate routing when developing other software.

The description says:

```
Are you tired of developing location aware apps and having to program your own  
GPS simulator? Do you want to cheat on foursquare, facebook, Tinder and whatsapp?

Use this application to simulate gps locations, routes or even KML files. 

You can:

-Define a static point location or a radius to jump on intervals  
 and watch how other apps believe that the position is correct.  
-Search for a route between two points and simulate   
 that you are following it.
-Upload a KML file to /sdcard/kml and simulate it's route 
 in the time specified.
```

Of course, if anyone is seriously looking at your location data, then after awhile they are going to notice the repetitiveness ...